# Export to new projection in QGIS 1.7

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, export

Suppose I have layers A and B.  I don't know their projections but by the looks of the map I know they are not the same.

In QGIS 1.6 I would use one of my favorite features:

```
Vector> Data Management Tools> Export to New Projection
```

What was nice about that feature is that you could export B to A's projection by selecting "choose projection from existing layer".  Hence you need not know A or B's projection.

In QGIS 1.7 the `Data management Tools` menu is much reduced and the `Export to New Projection` is missing.

Yes, I can do projections on the fly, and I can do `save as`.  The former is not useful if I want to convert B's projection to A's.  The latter does not give option to set projection from open layer.

I have tried to find different ways to access the `Export to New Projection` dialog without success.  Any tips?

Comment: "Export to New Projection" has been removed to decrease complexity and necessary maintenance for what was considered a duplicate of "Save as ...". If "choose projection from existing layer" is important to you, maybe file a feature request to add it to "Save as ...".

Comment: @underdark I can see the need to simplify but I think this was a useful feature.  I will try to add a feature request.  Right now I fallen back to using QGIS 1.6 for this task.

Comment: IMHO there is no point in saving a file in a projection that you don't know.

Comment: @Pablo Please see my comment to your answer below.

Comment: @Pablo The point is to make them align in some projection so the layer can be saved and read in R.  For my purposes I do not care about the projection so long as they are aligned.  There is a reason I asked the question I asked.

Comment: @Fred. That explains everything. Have you considered using ogr2ogr? You could write a very simple script to change the projection of all your files at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of answers and responses, I would say the right answer is that provided by underdark:

> "Export to New Projection" has been
>   removed to decrease complexity and
>   necessary maintenance for what was
>   considered a duplicate of "Save as
>   ...". If "choose projection from
>   existing layer" is important to you,
>   maybe file a feature request to add it
>   to "Save as ...".

In short, this is no longer possible in QGIS 1.7.

Instead, one would need to:

1. Find out all your layers' projections and use `save as` or;
2. Find out all your layers' projections, learn ogr2ogr, and write a script to export layers or ;
3. Use QGIS 1.6 to export the layer and then open in QGIS 1.7.

Given that I am no expert in GIS I would choose option 3.  (I guess that counts as a minus for QGIS 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no "choose projection from existing layer" you will need to know layer A projection.

1) Find layer A projection.
2) Save As... (layer B)
3) Choose the SRS, after the first use it should be avaliable in "Recently used".

For that you need 5 clicks.

Comment: Thanks. In QGIS 1.6 is 3 clicks and no need to spend time finding projection.  My layer A is "nominally" in Lambert Conformal Conic with datum ITRF92 which is not even in the CRS menu (though almost identical to WGS1984).  My layer B is from a Garmin eTrex where the datum had been set to WGS1984.  When I load both layers they do not overlay at all. BTAIM the point is that in QGIS1.6 I solved this in three clicks and in QGIS1.7 I had to come here, ask questions, and get smart responses.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have 'Enable 'on the fly' reprojection by default' on? As you don't care for the projection, just set it as WGS84.

The only problem with on-the-fly projections is that many tools (like `Vector->Research Tools->Select by Location`) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First you can set "On-fly" projection" on.
After right click on the interested layer, choose "Save as" 
Here you can select or change the coordinate system you want.
Save the layer as a new layer.

Comment: you realize that this question is two years old and for QGIS 1.7 where "Save as" wasn't even existing. Therefore your answer doesn't work for this old version